# Binary ASCII to QString and Writing Said QString to PlainTextEdit Widget

Tags: c++, qt

Each byte of the file I am reading corresponds to one ascii or ebcdic char. The line `textualFileCharacterString = QString::fromAscii(currentCharacterPointer, -1);` gives me a warning that `fromAscii()` does not exist, oddly enough though `fromUni8()` does exist and so does `fromLatin1()` Is there an include file I'm missing/is there a different way I can convert Binary Ascii to a QString. Below is the section of my code where the issue is, and the includes.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromAscii

```
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

#define BUF_LEN_1 1
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
```

//jump in code

```
   QString textualFileCharacterString;
    char currentCharacter;
    const char* currentCharacterPointer = &currentCharacter;
    while (bytePosition < 3200)
    {
        for(count = 0; count < 80; count ++)
        {
            file.seekg(bytePosition);
            file.read((char*)(&ASCIIorEBCDICchar[0]), BUF_LEN_1);
            if (EBCDICtoASCIIConvNeeded == TRUE)
                currentCharacter = ebc_to_ascii_table(ASCIIorEBCDICchar[0]); 
            else
                currentCharacter = ASCIIorEBCDICchar[0];

            textualFileCharacterString = QString::fromAscii(currentCharacterPointer, -1);
            ui->TextualFileHeaderPlainTextEdit->insertPlainText(textualFileCharacterString);
            count++;
            bytePosition++;
        }
        ui->TextualFileHeaderPlainTextEdit->insertPlainText("\n");
    }
    ui->TextualFileHeaderPlainTextEdit->insertPlainText("done");
    ui->TextualFileHeaderPlainTextEdit->setReadOnly(true);
}
```

Comment: The doc you linked to is a fairly old version of Qt, `QString::fromAscii()` was removed in Qt5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html

Comment: UTF-8 is backward compatible to ASCII, so I don't see the question here.

Comment: I don't actually have this code anymore, but I want to follow up. Would QString::fromUni8(), instead of fromAscii(), work in this exact implementation.

Comment: I indicated I don't have the code anymore because I would have just tested this myself.